# Adding Enterprise Keywords as Advanced Search Property

Tags: managed-property, crawled-property, enterprise-keywords, advanced-search

I'm trying to add the "enterprise keywords" field as a custom property in my Advanced Search web part.

I created a mapped property specifically for enterprise keywords, and mapped "ows_Keyword" and "TaxKeyword" to it. I made sure it is Searchable and Queryable.I selected "Include content from all crawled properties"

I waited a couple days, then edited my web part, and in the XML I added my new managed property "owskeywordAdvancedSearch" to the text in the PropertyDef and ResultTypes areas as explained in this [article](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/05/add-custom-properties-to-advanced-search.html).

I can't get it to display in the Properties drop down. Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Sylvie

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my issue. Or rather I resolved it, not sure if I fully understand why it was happening.

1. I should have just used the out of the box mapped property "TaxKeyword" since that is Enterprise Keywords. I didn't need to create a new one.
2. I needed to added the PropertyRef and PropertyDef several times throughout the xml text, 7 times to be exact. Whereas the guide I used only had it written in twice. I just copied all of the out-of-the-box "Description" property references and replaced "Description" with TaxKeyword.

Now it's working!